Why are the __bss_start and __bss_end names NOT addresses?
I'm building for a Xilinx 7000 Zynq dual ARM processor. I thought the linker was gnu, but now I'm not sure whether it is or not.
I can create a memory section in the linker script, with something like the following (ps7_ram_1 is a shared memory area but that's not really important here)
.shared_mem (NOLOAD) : {
    my_memory = .;
} > ps7_ram_1

From my C program, I can get the address of this with something like;-
extern char* my_memory;

...and sure enough, I can use that pointer to read and write to/from the memory and it's definitely referring to the expected address (the start of ps7_ram_1). This is behaving exactly as I would expect.
However, if I want to get the address of the start of .bss, I have to take the address of the __bss_start name; ie, &__bss_start (if I just use the name directly, I get zero, which is the contents of the .bss). It's acting as if __bss_start is the name of a (I assume? zero-sized) object. If I take the address in this way, I DO get to the start of .bss, but considering __bss_start and __bss_end are defined in the same way as my example above, ie;-
__bss_start = .;

...then why aren't the __bss_start and __bss_end names addresses already?
I should add that this pattern seems to be repeated across other standard memory sections and their start and end names
UPDATE...
I spotted the comment by Mark Ransom. Clearly I was confusing myself and the __bss_start name was behaving correctly. It was my my_memory name that was doing something odd.
Well, I slept on this and the next day, I fiddled some more and I found that the problem "went away". Yes, really. I have no idea except to say that I definitely was not imagining it - I spent quite some time looking at this and the issue was consistent. Anyway, I made my my_memory reference in my C code an object instead of a pointer and it works ok. I'm very puzzled, but I'm going to leave it for now and maybe come back to looking at it later

Please provide a [mre] including at least source, linker script, and compile and link commands sufficient to reproduce the issue.

Actually your __bss_start is working exactly like I would expect, it's your my_memory that's puzzling.

I have updated the post - Very odd.
@old_timer - Can you clarify the point you are making? I can't make any sense of it I'm afraid

It sounds like you are asking why bss start and end are not just automatically there and why do we have to place them?

@old_timer - no, I wasn’t asking that at all. Thanks for the input though
